# Return IEnumerable<Object> rather IEnumerable<IEnumerable><Object>

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

I need to join two tables and get the data from one of the table using linq.

The join works fine but it returns IEnumerable <$IEnumerable><$Ojbect> and I need IEnumerable<$Object>

Here is the code:

```
(
    from med in meds
    join pres in prescriptions
    on med.Code equals pres.Code into latstPrescrptions
    let allPrescriptions = latstPrescrptions.Where(
        pres => pres.PatientId == patientId 
            && (pres.PrescriptionEndDate > DateTime.Now)  
            || pres.PrescriptionEndDate == null
    )
    select allPrescriptions
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you want to "flatten" a collection, `SelectMany` is the construct you're looking for.

In LINQ Query Syntax, that's accomplished with multiple `from` clauses:

```
    from med in meds
    join pres in prescriptions
    on med.Code equals pres.Code into latstPrescrptions
    let allPrescriptions = latstPrescrptions.Where(
        pres => pres.PatientId == patientId 
            && (pres.PrescriptionEndDate > DateTime.Now)  
            || pres.PrescriptionEndDate == null
    )
    from prescription in allPrescriptions
    select prescription
```

Or, more simply:

```
    from med in meds
    join pres in prescriptions
    on med.Code equals pres.Code into latstPrescrptions
    from prescription in latstPrescrptions.Where(
        pres => pres.PatientId == patientId 
            && (pres.PrescriptionEndDate > DateTime.Now)  
            || pres.PrescriptionEndDate == null
    )
```

Looking at your query a little more closely, you could probably just avoid the `into` clause and rely on the `join` output to give you what you want, though.

```
    from med in meds
    join pres in prescriptions
    on med.Code equals pres.Code
    where pres.PatientId == patientId 
            && (pres.PrescriptionEndDate > DateTime.Now)  
            || pres.PrescriptionEndDate == null
    select pres
```

Comment: Thanks.. the first one worked can you please also convert the first one into lamda expression?

Comment: #Stripling is the last one works as left join?

Comment: @EngrUmair: I'm not going to try converting your LINQ Syntax into a lambda expression, but if you ever have an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<>>` that you want to unwrap, you can just do `.SelectMany(e => e)`.

Comment: @EngrUmair: All of these will behave like an inner join. You're asking for an `IEnumerable<Prescription>`: what would you expect to find there when there are meds without any prescriptions? It doesn't seem like null values would be particularly useful?